# Turn vector of dates into workable data frame

Tags: r

I have a vector dates with elements in the same format, like element 1 "Mon, 05 Sep 2013 01:19:18 -0000" .
I am trying to turn this vector into a data frame so I can manipulate them. For instance, I would like to be able to subtract 4 days from the first entry and get "Thu, 01 Sep 2013 01:19:18 -0000". I would also like to plot each element on a time line.

I have tried

```
as.Date(dates,'%a, %d %b %z %H:%M:%S %z')
```

and

```
for (d in dates){ 
    as.Date(d,'%a, %d %b %z %H:%M:%S -%z')
}
```

but I always get NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Try:

```
dates <- c("Mon, 05 Sep 2013 01:19:18 -0000", "Thu, 01 Sep 2013 01:19:18 -0000")    
strptime(dates, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

You just had a typo in the year argument (should be `%Y`, not `%z`). If you want to store the time as a date, add `as.Date` as you have done

```
as.Date(dates, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

If you want to make a data.frame and subtract 4 days from each date, try:

```
data.frame(date = strptime(dates, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'), 
subtracted = strptime(dates, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z') - as.difftime(4, unit="days"))
```

Note that R returns your system-specific times, which might differ from the times in your vector as specified by the `%z` argument (see `?strptime`).

Comment: Thanks! How could I go about changing the data frame, for instance subtracting 6 days from each entry.

Comment: strptime(dates, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z') - as.difftime(6, unit="days")

Comment: Thanks for help @MLEN. I edited the answer accordingly.